# SQL Increment the ID Column in Merge Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using Merge in sql server and when not matched i am inserting the values into the destination table. the destination table has a Unique ID Column with Values ID1,ID2,ID3,...etc.

Whenever i insert it using merge i call out a scalar valued function which increments the last value in table by 1 and returns it. When i call that function in Insert statement the entries inserted in Merge gets same ID. How can i Overcome this.

```
MERGE INTO Test
USING
(
SELECT   Name,UserName
from Test1
) AS Src
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (Id,Name,UserName) 
VALUES  ((SELECT GETID()),Name,UserName)
```

so when i run this code, even i get 10 entries in the table. all entries gets the same id.

Comment: Why are you using `GETID()`?  It would be better to create the `ID` column with `IDENTITY(1,1)` and let the database allocate the IDs automatically.

Comment: Use an identity column -- you can create a helper table for this if you don't already have one in the base table. (Almost) all other ways are doomed to failure, either because they won't be evaluated per-row or because the outcome will be nondeterministic.

Comment: I want the ID column to be associated with Text ID1,ID2,...

Comment: Actually the thing is that the ID looks like ID-18-001 which means ID-Year of inserting-Identity. So i make it as ID Column.

Comment: Why?  SQL-Server has built in functionality to manage id *(identity)* columns automatically.  But you want to re-invent that to have text values?  Which makes life *very* difficult and non-standard.  Unless you have an ***extemely*** good reason *(an I can't think of any I've ever encountered)* this is a bad idea.  I recommend using the functionality available to you, and then having other columns with the year, etc.  You could even have a computed column to concatenate the values in to your string.  But DON'T fart arse around reinventing `IDENTITY` columns.

Comment: min your going "text" route your already defeating the purpose of leveraging int/bigint datatypes to insert data on i.e. faster. Why not then just create a composite primary key for your target columns to merge by.

Comment: You can create a computed column that's defined as `'ID-18-' + FORMAT(ID, '000')`. Or you can just copy-paste this stuff in Excel, because if it's really 3 digits, you can't even have more than 1000 rows per year...